How to write a custom language worker with Typescript
We want to develop a custom Web Worker for our custom language with typescript. We already wrote a working Web Worker, but since the worker code imports monaco stuff from js files under esm directory (e.g. monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/common/languages), we lose the typing information. We attempted to import from monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js, but then the worker couldn't start (error message pasted below).
Relevant software:

"monaco-editor": "^0.46.0"
"vite": "^5.2.13"

Example of losing type (ILineTokens is identified as any):
// @ts-ignore
import * as languages from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/common/languages';
// ...
function doSomething(tokens: languages.ILineTokens): string {
// ...
}

Relevant piece of code:

JasmineWorker.ts

// @ts-ignore
import * as worker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker';
// @ts-ignore
import * as languages from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/common/languages';
// @ts-ignore
import { Position } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/common/core/position';
import IWorkerContext = worker.IWorkerContext;

// ...
export class JasmineWorker {
 private ctx: IWorkerContext;
 constructor(ctx: IWorkerContext, _createData: ICreateData) {
   this.ctx = ctx;
 }
 public async getCompletionItems(
   options: AutoCompleteOptions,
   word: IWordAtPosition,
   position: Position,
   range: languages.CompletionItemRanges
 ): Promise<languages.CompletionList> {
   // ...
 }
}
export function create(
 ctx: IWorkerContext,
 createData: ICreateData
): JasmineWorker {
 return new JasmineWorker(ctx, createData);
}

self.onmessage = () => {
 worker.initialize((ctx: IWorkerContext, createData: ICreateData) => {
   return new JasmineWorker(ctx, createData);
 });
};

export default JasmineWorker;


JasmineSourceEditor.ts

import { JasmineWorker } from './JasmineWorker';
import WorkerUrl from './JasmineWorker?worker&url';
// ...

self.MonacoEnvironment = {
 getWorker: function (_moduleId, label) {
   if (label === 'jasmine') {
     return new Worker(new URL('./JasmineWorker.ts', import.meta.url), {
       type: 'module',
     });
   }
   return new Worker(
     new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js', import.meta.url),
     { type: 'module' }
   );
 },
};

export class JasmineSourceEditor {
 // ...
 private autoCompleteDisposal: IDisposable | undefined;
 private worker: editor.MonacoWebWorker<JasmineWorker>;

 constructor(parent: HTMLElement, options: EditorOptions) {
   this.worker = editor.createWebWorker<JasmineWorker>({
     moduleId: WorkerUrl,
     label: 'jasmine',
     keepIdleModels: true,
     createData: {},
   });
 }

 registerCompletionItemProvider(options: AutoCompleteOptions): IDisposable {
   return monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('jasmine', {
     provideCompletionItems: async (model, position) => {
       await this.worker.withSyncedResources([model.uri]);
       const word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
       const range = {
         startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
         endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
         startColumn: word.startColumn,
         endColumn: word.endColumn,
       };
       const proxy = await this.worker.getProxy();
       const suggestions = proxy.getCompletionItems(
         options,
         word,
         position,
         range
       );
       return suggestions;
     },
   });
 }

 configureAutoComplete(options: AutoCompleteOptions): void {
   if (this.autoCompleteDisposal) {
     this.autoCompleteDisposal.dispose();
   }
   if (options.mode !== AutoCompleteMode.Disabled) {
     this.autoCompleteDisposal = this.registerCompletionItemProvider(options);
   }
   console.log(`auto complete configured`);
 }
}


We tried to import from editor.api.js because there's editor.api.d.ts like below:
import { editor } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
import { worker } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
import { languages } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
import { IPosition, IRange } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';

However, the worker could not start with the following errors:
Could not create web worker(s). Falling back to loading web worker code in main thread, which might cause UI freezes. Please see https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor#faq

and
Uncaught Error: Unexpected usage

Error: Unexpected usage
    at _EditorSimpleWorker.loadForeignModule (chunk-4C672B3V.js?v=b058a95f:9058:27)
    at chunk-UV56DTU5.js?v=b058a95f:29446:22
    at async Object.provideCompletionItems (JasmineSourceEditor.ts:90:9)
    at async monaco-editor.js?v=b058a95f:28834:22
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async provideSuggestionItems (monaco-editor.js?v=b058a95f:28822:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at chunk-7ATFQVGH.js?v=b058a95f:3090:21


I recommend not to import Monaco specific modules in your webworker. Not only gives this hard to solve problems, but makes the worker huge and usually you have multiple instances of a worker, so everything is duplicated each time. Instead do your language processing only with your own code and send the results to your main code, where you can have the glue code for Monaco specific stuff.
